# Spelling and plural of abbreviation "hi vis"

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography

We regularly use these "hi visibility jackets/vests":

[image: picture of the item in question]

We use them often enough to informally abbreviate it to simply "**hi vis**".

I am struggling as to how to pluralise such a term. In speech it sounds moderately okay to say "hi vises" but as you can see it looks terrible in writing. Any better suggestions?

Also would such a term be hyphenated?

Comment: even if it looks terrible, shouldn't it be "hi vises"? But as you say it's informally called "hi vis" within your professional community (I assume), in written form, I feel it should be the whole term. just my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

A few suggestions:

1. "Hi-vis jackets" / "Hi-vis vests". These have the most naturalness, at the cost of an extra word.
2. "Hi-vis". In a sentence you'd write, for instance, "we got a new batch of a dozen hi-vis today". *Could* be somewhat awkward.
3. Define a new abbreviation in whatever you're writing, like "HVJ" or "HVV", and write "HVJs" or "HVVs". Or even "HVs".  All it takes is putting a "(HV)" after the first mention: "A hi-vis (HV) is indispensable. How many HVs does it take…" etc.

My own preference is for 1 over 3 over 2. In any case, whatever you choose, do include a hyphen: it comes from "high-visibility jacket" where "high-visibility" is a multiple-word adjective that needs a hyphen.

Answer (score 4):

It's *extremely* uncommon for new singular words ending in "s" to be pronounced with a "z" sound; a "proper" spelling (even though one can never say that the spelling of a new word that isn't a brand name or technical coinage is proper until it has achieved a certain critical mass of usage) would probably be the hyphenated ***hi-viz***.

I would have pronounced "hi vis" as if it were the plural of "hi vi" if the term hadn't been explained, and I think that would be the first inclination of most readers.

The plural, if there is one, would probably be best spelled as ***hi-vizzes***, but there's probably a better way around it -- like instructing people to wear their hi-viz gear rather than their hi-vizzes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be hyphenated, hi-vis, making the plural hi-vises. I think from context it's clear that you don't mean a vise.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be more in keeping with usual English spelling to double the final 's' and get **hi visses** / **hi-visses**?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. It does indeed look less awful that way.

Answer (score 1):

As *vises* is an American English word (the plural of *vise*, which the equivalent of the British *vice*), I would use *hi vis's*.
If the word is preceded from an adjective, then I would write *hi-vis* for the singular and *hi-vis's* for the plural. *Hi vis* seems a greeting; that is the reason I would write *hi-vis* and *hi-vis's*, if I would really need to.

Comment: @Rhodri: I am not encouraging anything. Considering the context, I am suggesting what I think it is better. For sure I would not suggest _hi vises_ for the reason I reported.